# NSAttributedString Won't Save in Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsattributedstring

I'm using Parse as my backend and would like to save an `NSAttributedString` to it, but am getting the following error message:

`PFObject values may not have class: NSConcreteAttributedString`

Based on a few similar questions I've seen, it looks like I'll have to save it as HTML.

Is this the case and why is this required? Has anyone found a useful guide on how I can do this?

Comment: Parse.com doesn't store arbitrary iOS types directly.  Objects like attributed strings must be saved in a serialized form, like JSON.  See this for a hint on where to begin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620615/cocoa-how-to-save-nsattributedstring-to-json

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
object[@"objectText"] = [self.attributedString string];
```